# How to skip nested navigator's initial route?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigation like so:

```
Loading: SwitchNavigator {
  Auth: Stacknavigator,
  Main: StackNavigator,
  Onboard: StackNavigator,
}
```

every one of `StackNavigator`s has an initial route set. Under certain circumstances, I want to go from `loading` navigator to a specific route on `onboard` navigator. If I use just `navigator.navigate('DesiredRoute')`, it squeezes in also onboard's `initialRoute`, so the navstack looks like `[InitialRoute, DesiredRoute]` instead of `[DesiredRoute]`. How to get rid of the `InitialRoute`?

Code example:

```
// Loading.js

if (loadingComplete) {
  if (!user) {
    navigation.navigate('auth')
    return
  }
  if (user && userData) {
    navigation.navigate('Main')
    return
  }  
  if (onboardingCheckpointCleared) {
    // this creates `['InitialRoute', 'DesiredRoute']` instead of `['DesiredRoute']`
    navigation.navigate('DesiredRoute')
    return
  }
  navigation.navigate('Onboard')
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested myself with all the latest packages, but supposing that what you wrote is correct, how is this a problem? What are you trying to do? This does look a lot like a issue that could be solved elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior, if you want only `DesiredRoute` to appear then you have to set that route in `Loading` as well like below,

```
Loading: SwitchNavigator {
  Auth: Stacknavigator,
  Main: StackNavigator,
  Onboard: StackNavigator,
  DesiredRoute: ScreenName
}
```

Writing like this will not create any clash, you are safe to write.

Comment: @Zygro do you have any concerns with this answer or any other requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are navigating to `DesiredRoute` from outside the `Onboard` stack navigator

If you're outside the `Onboard` navigator, doing `navigation.navigate('DesiredRoute')` will trigger two actions: first, it will navigate to the `Onboard` stack navigator (so it will also activate the default sub screen of it `InitialRoute` like you call it) and then it will push the `DesiredRoute`. If you want to go to `Onboard` with only `DesiredRoute` on the stack, you can use the sub actions of the navigation actions like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Onboard', undefined, StackActions.replace('DesiredRoute'));
```

The third argument is an action that can be will be executed by the first argument navigator (if the first argument is not a screen but a navigator). Here it will navigate to the `Onboard` navigator and thus put the `InitialRoute` in the stack (automatically as it's the initialRoute of `Onboard`). However, the `StackAction.replace('DesiredRoute')` will be executed by the `Onboard` navigator and will replace `InitialRoute` with `DesiredRoute`.

See the official doc about the navigate: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom router that strips out the initial route when navigating to my nested stack:

```
const MyStackNav = createStackNavigator({ ...routes })

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyStackNav.router.getStateForAction
const customGetStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  const defaultNavState = defaultGetStateForAction(action, state)

  // If we're pushing onto a stack that only has a defaulted initialRoute
  if (
    !!defaultNavState &&
    !defaultNavState.routeName && 
    defaultNavState.isTransitioning &&
    defaultNavState.index === 1 &&
    action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE
  ) {
    const newState = {
      ...defaultNavState,
      index: 0, // Decrement index
      routes: defaultNavState.routes.slice(1), // Remove initial route
    }
    return newState
  }
  return defaultNavState
}
```